# how to create data tables in Html for following json, table column name may vary

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, datatables-1.10

**If possible give me jquery code for creating dynamic html table using dataTables plugin**

```
[
  ["Sales", {
    "2016-06-30": 102.18,
    "2014-12-31": 70.98,
    "2014-09-30": 86.41,
    "2014-03-31": 71.31,
    "2015-06-30": 87.59,
    "2014-06-30": 81.31,
    "2015-03-31": 74.58,
    "2015-12-31": 80.3,
    "2013-12-31": 71.24,
    "2016-03-31": 83.05,
    "2016-09-30": 97.93,
    "2015-09-30": 87.65
  }],
  ["Expenses", {
    "2016-06-30": 87.26,
    "2014-12-31": 66.6,
    "2014-09-30": 78.66,
    "2014-03-31": 68.09,
    "2015-06-30": 77.22,
    "2014-06-30": 73.9,
    "2015-03-31": 70.75,
    "2015-12-31": 69.57,
    "2013-12-31": 66.2,
    "2016-03-31": 73.83,
    "2016-09-30": 83.59,
    "2015-09-30": 76.56
  }],
  ["Operating Profit", {
    "2016-06-30": 14.92,
    "2014-12-31": 4.38,
    "2014-09-30": 7.75,
    "2014-03-31": 3.22,
    "2015-06-30": 10.37,
    "2014-06-30": 7.41,
    "2015-03-31": 3.83,
    "2015-12-31": 10.73,
    "2013-12-31": 5.04,
    "2016-03-31": 9.22,
    "2016-09-30": 14.34,
    "2015-09-30": 11.09
  }],
  ["OPM", {
    "2016-06-30": 14.6,
    "2014-12-31": 6.17,
    "2014-09-30": 8.97,
    "2014-03-31": 4.52,
    "2015-06-30": 11.84,
    "2014-06-30": 9.11,
    "2015-03-31": 5.14,
    "2015-12-31": 13.36,
    "2013-12-31": 7.07,
    "2016-03-31": 11.1,
    "2016-09-30": 14.64,
    "2015-09-30": 12.65
  }],
  ["Other Income", {
    "2016-06-30": 0.7,
    "2014-12-31": 1.24,
    "2014-09-30": 1.78,
    "2014-03-31": 2.68,
    "2015-06-30": 0.72,
    "2014-06-30": 1.52,
    "2015-03-31": 1.85,
    "2015-12-31": 0.84,
    "2013-12-31": 4.29,
    "2016-03-31": 1.85,
    "2016-09-30": 0.68,
    "2015-09-30": 0.82
  }],
  ["Depreciation", {
    "2016-06-30": 2.25,
    "2014-12-31": 2.35,
    "2014-09-30": 2.4,
    "2014-03-31": 2.56,
    "2015-06-30": 2.31,
    "2014-06-30": 2.4,
    "2015-03-31": 2.3,
    "2015-12-31": 2.34,
    "2013-12-31": 2.58,
    "2016-03-31": 2.28,
    "2016-09-30": 2.26,
    "2015-09-30": 2.38
  }],
  ["Interest", {
    "2016-06-30": 5.88,
    "2014-12-31": 6.12,
    "2014-09-30": 6.2,
    "2014-03-31": 4.94,
    "2015-06-30": 6.13,
    "2014-06-30": 5.96,
    "2015-03-31": 6.64,
    "2015-12-31": 5.96,
    "2013-12-31": 6.08,
    "2016-03-31": 5.88,
    "2016-09-30": 5.82,
    "2015-09-30": 6.21
  }],
  ["Profit before tax", {
    "2016-06-30": 7.5,
    "2014-12-31": -2.85,
    "2014-09-30": 0.93,
    "2014-03-31": -1.6,
    "2015-06-30": 2.65,
    "2014-06-30": 0.58,
    "2015-03-31": -3.27,
    "2015-12-31": 3.28,
    "2013-12-31": 0.66,
    "2016-03-31": 2.91,
    "2016-09-30": 6.94,
    "2015-09-30": 3.32
  }],
  ["Tax", {
    "2016-06-30": 2.53,
    "2014-12-31": -0.45,
    "2014-09-30": 0.16,
    "2014-03-31": -0.57,
    "2015-06-30": 0.99,
    "2014-06-30": 0.11,
    "2015-03-31": -0.36,
    "2015-12-31": 0.06,
    "2013-12-31": 0.24,
    "2016-03-31": 0.55,
    "2016-09-30": 2.46,
    "2015-09-30": 1.21
  }],
  ["Net Profit", {
    "2016-06-30": 4.96,
    "2014-12-31": -2.4,
    "2014-09-30": 0.77,
    "2014-03-31": -1.02,
    "2015-06-30": 1.66,
    "2014-06-30": 0.46,
    "2015-03-31": -2.9,
    "2015-12-31": 3.22,
    "2013-12-31": 0.43,
    "2016-03-31": 2.36,
    "2016-09-30": 4.48,
    "2015-09-30": 2.11
  }]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure of your data this should work:

```
var columns = [];
var dates = [];
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var key in arr[i][1]) {
    if (dates.indexOf(key) === -1) {
      dates.push(key)
    }
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  var tempObj = {
    date: dates[i],
  }
  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    //console.log(arr[x][0], arr[x][1][dates[i]])
    tempObj[arr[x][0]] = arr[x][1][dates[i]]
  }
  data.push(tempObj)
}
for (var key in data[0]) {
  columns.push({
    title: key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.substring(1),
    data: key
  });
}
console.log(dates);
console.log(data);
console.log(columns);
$(function() {
  $("#example").DataTable({
    "columns": columns,
    "data": data
  });
});
```

Hope that helps. Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/nLpem02t/).

Comment: Thanks alot for the solution , This works great as I expected